# CKEDITOR move cursor to end of selection

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to move cursor at the end of selection, for example I have:

```
some |text| abc
```

where | is selection start and end

and I neet to position cursor here:

```
some text^ abc
```

removing the selection

How can I achieve this? I tried editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0] and modifiying startOffset but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but for anyone looking the answer (assuming a CKEditor instance named `editor1`):

```
const range = editor1.getSelection().getRanges()[0];
const endNode = range.endContainer;
const endOffset = range.endOffset;
range.setStart(endNode, endOffset);
range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);
editor1.getSelection().selectRanges([range]);
editor1.focus();
```